# Some question in computing Groebner basis

Tags: proof-verification, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis, groebner-generators

> **Problem:** Let $G = \{z^5 - z^2, -z^3+y^2,x-1-yz^4\}$ and $I$ be an ideal which is  generated by $G$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$.
>
> 1. Show that $G$ is a Groebner basis of $I$ with lexicographic ordering $x>y>z$.
> 2. Show that $G$ is not a Groebner basis of $I$ with graded lexicographic ordering $x>y>z$.
> 3. Find a Groebner basis of $I \cap \mathbb{C}[y,z]$ with lexicographic ordering $y>z$.
> 4. Find the variety of ideal $I$.
> 5. Is the polynomial $f = 4xyz^6 - z^3xy - 2z^3y^2 + 2y^4 - yz^4 - 3z^2x^2 + 3xz^2 + x$ in $I$? Explain why?

**My attempt:**

1. Let $g_1 = z^5 - z^2, g_2 = -z^3+y^2, g_3 = x-1-yz^4$. We compute
   $$S(g_1,g_2) = y^2(z^5-z^2) - z^5(y^2-z^3) = -y^2z^2 + z^8$$
   $$\overline{S(g_1,g_2)}^G = 0$$
   $$S(g_1,g_3) = x(z^5-z^2) - z^5(x-yz^4-1) = -xz^2 + yz^9 + z^5$$
   $$\overline{S(g_1,g_3)}^G = 0$$
   $$S(g_2,g_3) = x(y^2-z^3) - y^2(x-yz^4-1) = -xz^3 + y^3z^4 + y^2$$
   $$\overline{S(g_2,g_3)}^G = 0$$
   So $G = \{g_1,g_2,g_3\}$ is a Groebner basis of $I$ with the lexicographic ordering.
2. With the graded lexicographic ordering, $g_1=z^5-z^2, g_2=yz^3-y^2, g_3=-yz^4+x-1$ we compute
   $$S(g_1,g_3) = y(z^5-z^2) + z(-yz^4+x-1) = -yz^2+xz+z$$
   $$\overline{S(g_1,g_3)}^G = -yz^2+xz+z \ne 0$$
   Hence $G = \{g_1,g_2,g_3\}$ is not a Groebner basis of $I$ with graded lexicographic ordering.
3. We have $G = \{z^5-z^2,y^2-z^3,x-yz^4-1\}$ is a Groebner basis of $I$ with the lexicographic ordering $x>y>z$, so this implies a Groebner basis of $I \cap \mathbb{C}[y,z]$ with the lexicographic ordering $y>z$ is
   $$G' = \{z^5-z^2,y^2-z^3\}$$

For the last question, I have did it. I have arranged $f$ follows the lexicographic, $f = -3x^2z^2+4xyz^6-xyz^3+3xz^2+x+2y^4-2y^2z^3-yz^4$, since $LT(f) \notin \langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),LT(g_3) \rangle$, hence $f \notin I$.

I need help in two questions $4$ and $5$. Thank all!

Comment: What's the range of an ideal? Ad 5: divide $f$ into the Groebner basis.

Comment: The original question $4$ is find the set of all roots of $I$. I have translate into range of $I$, but i'm not sure it clarify the meaning.

Comment: Roots means zero locus or variety.

Comment: @Wuestenfux I have edited it.

Comment: In [M2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/) `primaryDecomposition I` gives `{ideal(x-1,z^2,y^2), ideal(z-1,y-1,x-2), ideal(z-1,y+1,x), ideal(y-1,x-z-1,z^2+z+1), ideal(y+1,x+z-1,z^2+z+1)}`. Also `(-3*x^2*z^2+4*x*y*z^6-x*y*z^3+3*x*z^2+x+2*y^4-2*y^2*z^3-y*z^4)%I` gives `1`.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I didn't understanded what you said.

Comment: The documentation for [%](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.14/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/__pc.html) and [`primaryDecomposition`](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.14/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_primary_spdecomposition.html)

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland So, $f \in I$ or $f \notin I$?

Comment: The remainder is $1$ and not $0$, so $f\not\in I$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Thanks. But does my proof $LT(f) \notin \langle LT(g_1),LT(g_2),LT(g_3) \rangle$ implies $f \notin I$ correct??

Comment: Yes. I wanted you to note that $f-1$ is in $I$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland I understand this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a note the zero locus of $I$ can be found by restricting the Groebner basis:

$G_2 = G\cap{\Bbb C}[z] = \{z^5-z^2\}$, $G_1 = G\cap{\Bbb C}[y,z] = \{y^2-z^3,z^5-z^2\}$, and $G_1=G$.

First, determine the zero locus of $G_2$ (single complex polynomial in $z$), then extend the zero locus to the zero locus of $G_1$ (taking the zeros you already have for $z$ and determine the corresponding values of $y$), and finally extend the zero locus ot the zero locus of $G$ (similar to the previous step).

More specifically, $z^5-z^2 = z^2(z^3-1)=0$ and the zeros are $0$ (twofold) and the third roots of unity $\xi^0= 1,\xi = e^{2\pi/3},\xi^2$.

Then consider the roots of $y^2-z^3$ using the already computed values for $z$. For $z=0$, one has $y=0$ (twofold) and for $z=1$ one has $y^2=1$, i.e., $y=\pm 1$, for $z=\xi$ one has $y^2=\xi$ and so $y$ is a primitive 6th root of unity, namely $y=e^{2\pi i/6}$ or $y=e^{2\pi i 5/6}$. And so on.

For the last problem, divide $f$ into the Groebner basis. The nice property of Groebner bases is that the residue is zero iff $f\in I$.

Comment: Could you explain more explicitly about question $4$.

Comment: Shoud I find roots of $x-yz^4-1$?

Comment: Yes, but with the values of $y$ and $z$ already given. Then $x=yz^4+1$ and the right-hand side is always a constant.

Comment: For $z=\xi^2$, so $y^2 = \xi^2 \Rightarrow y = \pm \xi = \pm e^{2 \pi i/3}$?

Comment: For $z = e^{2 \pi /3}, y = e^{2 \pi i /6}$, I couldn't figured out $x$ is a constant because of the $i$.

Comment: Its just a complex number. $z=e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Comment: I have arranged $f$ follows the lexicographic, $f = -3x^2z^2+4xyz^6-xyz^3+3xz^2+x+2y^4-2y^2z^3-yz^4$, so $LT(f)$ didn't divisible by $LT(g_1),LT(g_2),LT(g_3)$. So $f \notin I$.